# How to Supress Report footer on grouping

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using the below crystal report to display my record and also to group using the column batch . The Main report works fine , however, when i group by  a particular batch, The report print the group footer and proceed down with another empty long row to the end of the page. I tried to fix this but i dont seem to get it going yet. I set the report and page footer to supress blanc spaces yet nothing change.

Also when printing the report, it print an empty grand total row on each page. This also i am not sure why it does that. PLs any suggestion would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I can see two times column headings and two times summation.. why are those included 2 times? any specific reason?

Comment: The first is for the report header and footer . The second is for the group header and footer respectively sir.

Comment: May be you are getting page footer.. try to supress and check

Comment: I supress the page footer and its still the same sir. I was thinking may the the report footer, however, the report footer is where my row grandtotal is . If i supress it will not show.

Comment: I am unsure what's happening there but one final suggestion is try to limit all fields, lines of report footer to fit to the section and not extending beyond the section

Comment: Very helpful sir, indeed that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just like suggested by siva .It turned out, i use a single line to divide the columns of the report. That say, both the report footer and the group footer rows will while grouping ,because the same vertical line transverse through . When i minimize the lines and restrict each to it section , the error goes away.